# Modify table column data on button click

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a Leave Management System using PhP-Mysql.

I have a table which takes input from user while applying for their leaves.
(name, leavetype, fromdate, todate, supervisor, reason and status). Only the status column has a predefined value 'pending'.

Now I want to introduce two buttons (Accept/Reject) on each row. Which on click will change the value for Status field.

I am not sure how to do it, I have tried updating the table column but it updates only if there is a where Condition, which will not be the correct procedure for such case.

```
<div id="content">   
<?php
$connect = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","leavedb"); 
$sql = "SELECT 
name,
leavetype,
fromdate,
todate,
supervisor,
reason,
DATEDIFF(todate,fromdate) as Days,
status as Status
FROM leavereq";
$result = $connect->query($sql);    
?>

<table id="myTable">
    <tr>                                                
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Leave Type</th>   
        <th>From Date</th>
        <th>To Date</th>
        <th>Supervisor</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
        <th>No. of Days</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>                                   

    <?php
        while ($report=$result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {                                 
        echo "<tr>";  
        echo "<td>".$report['name']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$report['leavetype']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['fromdate']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['todate']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['supervisor']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['reason']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['Days']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['Status']."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . '<input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve">' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . '<input type="submit" name="reject" value="Reject">' . "</td>";                                
        }
    ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//In the html : You have to add unique id for every <td> of status & also wants to change the input type of approve & reject...also require javascript
// check below
<script>
function function_name(status_id,req)
{
var status;
status='status'+status_id;
if(req=='approve')
{
document.getElementById(status).innerHTML='approve';
//pass ajax call to update entry in db
}
else if(req=='reject')
{
document.getElementById(status).innerHTML='reject';
//pass ajax call to update entry in db
}
</script>

<table id="myTable">
    <tr>                                                
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Leave Type</th>   
        <th>From Date</th>
        <th>To Date</th>
        <th>Supervisor</th>
        <th>Reason</th>
        <th>No. of Days</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>                                   

    <?php
$i=0;
        while ($report=$result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {                                 
        echo "<tr>";  
        echo "<td>".$report['name']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$report['leavetype']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['fromdate']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['todate']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['supervisor']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['reason']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$report['Days']."</td>";
        echo "<td id='status$i'>pending</td>";
        echo "<td>" . '<button type="button" name="approve"'.$i.' onClick="return function_name($i,approve);">Approve</button>' . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . '<button type="button" name="reject"'.$i.' onClick="return function_name($i,reject);">Reject</button>' . "</td>";  
        $i++;                              
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Not working. One addition column shows with predefined value of 'pending' But nothing happens after clicking Accept/Reject button

Comment: where does the 'status_id' gets its value from ?

Comment: Its a dynamic creation of status_id... check code in details... : <td id='status$i'>pending</td>... After that if you don't get it... then i sure you are not doing any searching...